# Facebook 'scheduled_publish_time' => UNIX TIMESTAMP (TimeZone Issue)

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, unix-timestamp

How do i go about the Timezone Issue for UNIX TIMESTAMP ? I set my

Server Time Zone +8 / SGT

Time at 
**16**:22:54

Date at 
2013-10-**15**

When i check facebook, i get this

```
Wednesday, 16 October 2013 at 07:22 GMT+8
```

Code i use to create unix TimeStamp

```
$unixTimeStamp = strtotime($retrievedScheduled);
```

I need to minus 1 day 15 hours to post correctly... Something is very wrong here. My server time is correct to +8

Comment: You haven't really told us what the problem is.  What is the question?  The times don't match, but it could be your server time setting, have you confirmed that it is correct?

Comment: @Coulton Well, my server has to run at my Timezone Time. When i POST x Datetime, facebook sees it differntly

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore"); 
$combinedDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date $time"));
```

Fixed

My date and time  from 2 different variables

Time at 16:22:54

Date at 2013-10-15